# drupal reset password page not directing properly

Tags: drupal-6

My password reset page is not functioning correctly.  After a user clicks the link in his email to reset his password it goes to the reset page at:
http://[sitename].com/user/reset/40/1317793871/1541333e89b19dbdc93b3e47f6d91a41

The user then clicks the login button on that page, and it goes to some arbitrary file:
http://[sitename].com/sites/all/themes/[sitename]/type/amaranth/AmaranthBold.ttf  (This is a font file I uploaded for the css.)

Has anyone encountered such a thing or know why it would be happening.  I really can't figure how to correct this or how to get around it.

Comment: I deleted the .ttf font file it was going to and now it redirects to:
http://[sitename]/system/files/a.swf

it just seems so random... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The CUSTOM ERROR module was causing form redirection problems. When I removed this module, my password reset page and form redirected properly.